# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ToolbarAndroid

Tags: android, react-native

I've started [react-tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kL7DivA0FwM) and got following error:

[image]

The component is defined as follows:

```
export default class CounterComponent extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ToolbarAndroid title="counter demo" />
                    <Text> Counter Component
                    </Text>
                </View>
        );
    } }
```

`App.js` contains following code other then import:

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Counter/>
    );
  }
}
```

I've index.js in root but no `index.android.js` with following content:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('VishnuTest', () => App);
```

I'm not sure why its not able to find the `ToolbarAndroid`. It works without this statement.

Comment: Did you import ToolbarAndroid from react-native?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import this lines in your `CounterComponent` class

```
import {ToolbarAndroid} from 'react-native';
```

hope it'll helps you...